# EntityFramework Join with MVC C# not displaying anything

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using EntityFramework which creates a local database and I would like to perform Join operation to show the Purchases done for each Customer, but I can't see to make it work.

Here is my Customer Model

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int custId { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string addresss { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Purchase Model

```
public class Purchase
    {
        public int purchaseId { get; set; }
        public int custId { get; set; }
        public int productId { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }

        public double deliveryFees { get; set; }
        public double finalAmount { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime dateOfPurchase { get; set; }
 
    }
```

I have tried to create a ViewModel which should keep each Model in the class, so that I could perform join and it is shown down below:

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
        public Purchase purchase { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> customers;
        public List<Purchase> purchases;
    }
```

And I have created a Controller for ViewModel to try to

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (db)
            {
                var cust = (from p in db.PurchaseList
                            join c in db.Customers on p.custId equals c.custId
                            select new
                            {
                                id = p.custId,
                                firstName = c.firstName,
                                surname = c.surname,
                                total = p.finalAmount.ToString()
                            }

                    ).ToList();
                return View(cust);
            }
        }
```

The db variable is the context of the database that I am using.

```
public Context() : base("name=Context")
        {
        }
         public void CreateDatabase()
        {

        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.Offer> Offers { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.User> Users { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.Purchase> PurchaseList { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
```

In my View page I am only doing a foreach to retrieve the data but it is always empty. Do you have any suggestion? Should I use a different approach to the above?

Comment: Can you reproduce a similar query on the database and check the results there? Something like: 
`SELECT CustId, Firstname, Surname, FinalAmount 
FROM PurchaseList 
INNER JOIN Customer ON PurchaseList.CustomerId = Customer .CustId`.

Comment: The database is created in the program, I do not have an attached database, but I will try to do it and print in the web page

Comment: What is db? The datacontext?

Comment: @Selthien correct

Comment: @FelipeOriani I get this error now when executing it 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Data.Purchase'. A member of the type, 'purchaseId', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

Comment: It sounds like there is something wrong with your database. You should add what your db context looks like. Also, is this throwing an error or is it literally returning 0 records? Did you add a break point to see how many items are returned? You can also hit f12 to view the network tab as you make the request and check the response. Make sure you are actually getting 0 records.

Comment: I have added the db Context in my question. It is throwing a CommandExecutionException therefore the var "cust" is always null

Answer (score 0):

Have you given correct relationships in your dbContext class?

[Refer my sample application](https://github.com/AvanthaSiriwardana/TheProjector-V1.0)

(https://github.com/AvanthaSiriwardana/TheProjector-V1.0/blob/master/TheProjector.Domain/Entities/TheProjectorContext.cs)

Comment: I have added data from the Server explorer rather than seeding the database as you did, and the context have been added to the question.

Comment: Only 3 things come to my mind. 

1. Database tables are properly designed with foreign keys 
2. You have configured database with the correct connection string in the startup class
3. Run the same query in SQL server and check if data is getting populated